# d3.js is slowing the performance

Tags: d3.js

The below mentioned snippet is slowing the performance. I am unable to find a better for this. its used to display table and its child rows as well. 
Can someone help me in optimizing this snippet for better use.

THanks in advance

```
        childRow.transition()
                                .duration(duration)
                                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                                    //on transitions when clicked the child 
        rows are recalculated and placed accordingly on page
                                    childRow.selectAll('rect').remove();
                                    childRow.selectAll('text').remove();
                                    for(var childRectCount = 0; childRectCount < configDataCopy.details.length; childRectCount++)
                                    {
                                        childRow.append("rect")
                                                .attr("height", rowHeight)
                                                .attr("width", rectWidth)
                                                .attr("id", function(d){ return "a" + d.key;})
                                                .attr("x", (childRectCount * rectWidth))
                                                .attr("class", function(d){
                                                    return d.zebra === true ? "wl-widget-row-not-striped" : "wl-widget-row-striped";
                                                });

                                        childRow.append("text")
                                                .attr("dy", dy)
                                                .attr("dx", function(d){
                                                    return childRectCount === 0 ? (childRectCount * rectWidth) + firstColumnPadding : (childRectCount*rectWidth);
                                                })
                                                .text(function(d) {
                                                    return d[configDataCopy.details[childRectCount].key];
                                                });
                                    }
                                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                                })
                                .style("opacity", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing all elements and re-adding them again, use the ENTER/UPDATE/EXIT pattern.

Comment: I am not aware of this. If possible please provide some link about it. That would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: And I need to mention that, removing is happening only once. loop is for appending.

Comment: Yes but once you remove, nodes are created from scratch and re-appended. It is faster to remove only nodes that need to be removed and modify the ones that needs modification.

Comment: It's bit painful to get used to, but you might find it faster.